# Auto click a button in WinForms application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I have a WinForms application and it has a button in it. I want that when this win form application starts to run, it automatically clicks on its button. Which codes should I add to it to run like this?

---

this is code:

```
    public void SendData()
    {

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id1").SetAttribute("value","something");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id2").SetAttribute("value","something");

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Submit").InvokeMember("click");


    }
```

When I call `SendData()` programs doesn't run and show no errors. But when I put button and I click on it myself it works.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://example.com");

            Thread.Sleep(10000); 
            SendData();
        }

        public void SendData()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id1").SetAttribute("value", "something");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id2").SetAttribute("value", "something");
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Submit").InvokeMember("click");

        }
    }
}
```

This is whole code. Test it. It does not work. It has no error but doesn`t run. The form should display but nothing happens.

Comment: Show your code. Also if the code in the button was in its own routine, you could just call that routine anywhere you want.

Comment: Why do you want to click on the button? How about simply running the same code?

Comment: no bady can help me?:(

Comment: this is the code  help please:(

Answer (score -1):

When form loads OnShown event fires, call the same function that your button calls. No need to simulate the click.

or

```
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
    base.OnShown(e);
    this.BtnClick(null, null);
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I took to long to look that event name up. In any case, it is rather important that code is executed *earliest* in OnShown. Any earlier event might run into issues with the Forms elements not yet being around.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have web browser control on your form so when the shown event is fired may be web browser is not completely loaded.
Can you try to call the code after your browser is loaded.

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
 WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.ondocumentcompleted?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: i make an sleep code to web browser load completely.but it didn't work.I  don't know what should i do.every thing is okay when i debug it but it doesn't run and show no errors when i debug it!!!!